# Spring Boot swagger-ui.html 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to setup swagger ui for my spring boot application but when I go to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui` I got 404 not found. I tried it with `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` and `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html` but still got a 404. I have looked at countless tutorial and forms question but the problem continues. Here are my dependencies and swagger config file

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.10'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}


group = 'com.company'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.1.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
}
```

SwaggerConfig.java:

```java
package com.company.app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

I assume it is about the versions, which one should I use with the spring boot version I am using if it is about versions of swagger?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with changes in `SwaggerConfig.java`, I extended the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` in `SwaggerConfig` and overrided `void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)`
:

```java
package com.company.app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

         registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
     }
}
```